# Can we increase the limit of chat stars available per day?

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

It's 15:39 and I've already used up my star allowance for the day. This is a regular occurrence.

[image: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!]

Why is the star limit set at what it is? Could this limit be raised to a slightly larger, yet still reasonable value?

Comment: I would have starred this in chat, but I've used up my vote allowance :(

Comment: It's the Bridge, you all star everything that's even remotely funny out of context, as such... you run out of stars! Maybe you should just control your urges a bit more!

Comment: @sixlettervariables I've put in a screenshot of the banner that comes up.

Comment: As far as slightly larger but still reasonable values go, could be 25, 30, 42, 50

Comment: To answer the question in the title, yes. This limit was implemented in direct response to the behaviour of a few people.

Comment: I saw the title and thought the question would be the opposite of what it is.

Comment: I think I've only ever reached my vote allowance in chat twice.  Although I guess I'm not the greatest metric to measure the average chat user by.

Comment: @TimStone So if a few people abuse the system we need to make it worse for everybody? :(

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3562233#3562233

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Luckily comment upvotes don't run out. Actually, they probably do.

Comment: @fredley Yup, they absolutely do.

Comment: @TimStone: Yes.  This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey :(

Comment: Hmm I have upvoted every single thing on this page, and I haven't run out of any votes yet....

Comment: "[I don't have stars so I'll just have to use flags now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9351444#9351444)"

Comment: @ryan: You can only cast a comment vote every 5 seconds.  Comments have other rate limits too.

Comment: [I support this because it means I will live longer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=5464058#5464058)

Comment: @RobertHarvey yea I know, and its really annoying that it restarts the 5 seconds if you miss it! :P who's bright idea was that?

Comment: This is what happens when you don't have rate limits: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PruY9.png.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery There isn't a rate limit currently (well, only at a very granular level).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything on Stack Exchange is rate-limited in some way.

I don't recall ever using up all my stars in chat, but if you've ever used stars in chat, you already know that your star can push other people's starred posts off the starred list, so unrestrained starring is not exactly victimless.

Comment: I would happily pay for more stars. I've got a few Unicorn dollars lying around here somewhere...

Comment: On at least one occasion in Arqade's chat someone's spammed their entire daily allotment of stars on random recent messages within like 1 minute

Comment: @BenBrocka Wouldn't a system where a greater number of stars were available, yet rate-limited solve everyone's problems?

Comment: We need to flag the star spammers.  Then we need flag checkers to ban those folks.  Then we need people to check the flag checkers, and automated reviews for everyone.  On second thought, maybe the limit is OK where it is.